# VBA Copying cells to another worksheet where cells have the same value

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets I'm working with with long serial numbers as the cell values. One sheet (Sheet1) has a list of each individual serial number hyperlinked to a webpage referring to that item. This list ranges from A1:A31.

The second sheet (Sheet2) has a massive list of those same serial numbers, but in range G1:G102. The difference is that this list is not hyperlinked, and the serial numbers sometimes show up multiple times. There are also some areas where a cell is blank, so it splits up the continuous column of data.

I would essentially like to write a macro that takes the first list in Sheet1, and for each cell, it compares it to each cell in Sheet2 column G. Then, if the values match, I would like to copy the hyperlinked cell from Sheet 1 and paste it to that cell with the same value in Sheet2. Therefore, Sheet2 column G now has a fully populated list of hyperlinked serial numbers.

Can anyone help me with this? This is what I have so far...doesn't seem to work:

```
Sub CopyHyperlinks()

Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim myRange As Excel.Range
Dim newRange As Excel.Range

Set myRange = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contents").Range("A1:A31")
Set newRange = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G1:G102")

For Each cell In myRange
    If myRange.Cells.Value = newRange.Cells.Value Then newRange.Cells.Value = myRange.Cells.Value
Next cell

End Sub'
```

Comment: is the url the same, except for the difference in serial number? (am asking, because you can do this only with formulas if this is the case). Better yet, please post a screenshot of the two data sets. That will help a lot.

Comment: Please check the [HYPERLINK](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/HYPERLINK-function-333C7CE6-C5AE-4164-9C47-7DE9B76F577F)-function. it may do all you are looking for

Comment: You are using `For Each cell in myRange`, but then never actually use `Cell`.  Don't confuse `Cells` with your `cell` variable.  Try just doing `If .cel.value = `, but then you need to fix the `newRange.Cells.Value`, to incorporate the `cell`. Do you just want to see if `myRange` has a cell that's in the entire `newRange` sheet?

Comment: I'm not sure how to post pictures :/ Thank you for the advice guys, but basically I want to go through newRange (this has serial numbers that are not hyperlinked yet) and replace those cells with the hyperlinked equivalents in myRange.

Comment: For example, myRange may have a cell with value 12345 that is hyperlinked. newRange may have a cell with value 12345 that is just a value, not hyperlinked. How can I compare the two data sets, and wherever there is a match, replace the non-hyperlinked cell with a hyperlinked one. I understand there are other functions to do this, I'm just wondering if anyone knows this specific way of doing it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

See [this little function](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/700076-vlookup-return-hyperlink.html). Put this:

```
Function GetHyperLinkAddress(rng As Range) As String
Dim hl As Hyperlink
For Each hl In rng.Parent.Hyperlinks
    If hl.Range.Address = rng.Address Then
        GetHyperLinkAddress = hl.Address
        Exit Function
    End If
Next hl
GetHyperLinkAddress = "Not Found"
End Function
```

in a module. In the Spreadsheet, add

```
=GetHyperLinkAddress(Cell#)
```

Next to the cells with the hyperlink. You could then just use a vlookup to match.